# swift3 cast int to indexPath

Tags: swift3

is there any chance to cast an Integer to the indexPath ?

Because I need the text out from the cell when I press the button. Or can I use a String as a sender for the Button?

```
cell.uncheckbox.tag = indexPath.row as! IndexPath

cell.uncheckbox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.btnClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)




func btnClicked(sender: UIButton)
{

    let row = sender.tag
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: row) as! TableViewCell;

    print("cellentext \(cell.textLabel?.text)")
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please check the indention of your code snippet or output. It somehow looks off. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are currently do is get a new cell for the row in which the button is. Which is probably not what you need.

```
let row = sender.tag
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: row) as! TableViewCell;
```

What you want is use the `tag` as the row parameter in your `IndexPath`. You can construct your own IndexPath like this, supposing you only have one section:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tag, section: 0)
```

And then use it to get your current cell by using the `cellForRow(at: IndexPath)`method of your `UITableView`.

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Hope that helps.